# how to add table layout on alertDialog?

Tags: android

I want to create custome dialog with table view , but dialog is not showing when i click on button.This is method called in button's onClick listener.....

```
public void dialogTable(){
    int i;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(alertView);
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)alertView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TransactionDetails transactionDetails = new TransactionDetails();   //POJO class

    for( i=0; i < 4; i++ ){

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        textView1.setText(transactionDetails.getCustomerNo());
        tableRow.addView(textView1);

        TextView textView2 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        textView2.setText(transactionDetails.getAmount().toString());
        tableRow.addView(textView2);

        TextView textView3 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        textView3.setText(transactionDetails.getStatus());
        tableRow.addView(textView3);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Instead of AlertDialog.Builder use Dialog and try

Comment: @suraj is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the error is that your are using the wrong context to inflate your layout. You have to use the builder context as [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)):

You have to use the same context to create your widgets.
This code works:

```
public void dialogTable(View view)
{

    int i;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Context dialogContext = builder.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(dialogContext);
    View alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(alertView);
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)alertView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TransactionDetails transactionDetails = new TransactionDetails();
    for( i=0; i < 4; i++ ){

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(dialogContext);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                                         (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(dialogContext);
        textView1.setText(transactionDetails.getCustomerNo());
        tableRow.addView(textView1);

        TextView textView2 = new TextView(dialogContext);
        textView2.setText(transactionDetails.getAmount().toString());
        tableRow.addView(textView2);

        TextView textView3 = new TextView(dialogContext);
        textView3.setText(transactionDetails.getStatus());
        tableRow.addView(textView3);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score -4):

Firstly you should check listener of your button whether right, secondly you should try to set a text color to your TextView.

```
textView.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question asked?

Comment: Sorry about that. But his code works for me, so I think maybe there are some problems in his button listener. About secondly, i forgotten to set color for my TextView,

Comment: and the TextView can't be seen, because there is white color.I just want to remind.